# Is it possible to stop Visual Studio 2008 from failing to build on CSS errors?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, css

I have an external stylesheet that has specific IE-hacks.  Every so often my site will fail to build due to these hacks (it is the hash-hack; for example **`#margin-top:-2px;`**).  This is the error:

> Unexpected character sequence. Expected a property name for the
>   " : " declaration

I haven't found out a concrete way to get the errors to stop, VS2008 just seems to stop caring after a while.  I found [this article](http://www.carlj.ca/2008/01/05/adding-css-colors-to-visual-studio-2005/), but I am unsure of how to edit the files properly so this "error" (since it is legal syntax) will not pop up again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure about 2008, but in 2005 (IIRC), you can go to:

```
 Tools | Options | Text Editor | CSS | CSS Specific
```

and then untick **Detect Errors**

I remember having exactly the same problem on 100% valid CSS which MS didn't recognise (big shock), flicked this switch and forgot about the problem forever more.

Comment: Didn't work for me at first.  It worked after closing all the documents, then closing VS and finally relaunching the program.

Comment: Yeah VS is a killer for that - same problem J.Sheehan describes.

Answer (score 2):

Tools | Options | Text Editor | HTML | Validation

Make sure 'Show Errors' 'As Warnings' is checked. There was a bug early on that even if it was checked, it wasn't acknowledged, in which case, uncheck it and save the settings, then go back and check it again.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to close the file in the editor and it should stop complaining.

Comment: Man I hate Visual Studio sometimes...Maybe we can find a more "automated" way of preventing this error?

Comment: I get it with the web.config all day long. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179927/how-to-resolve-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-elementattribute-xxx

Comment: +1. Exactly: just close the file with the offending lines CSS / JS lines and all of a sudden the errors are gone (and occasionally a real error may become apparent in the list, which actually prevented the compile cycle to succeed).