# Two projects with the same App.config, one of them doesn't compile

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config, settings

I have two windows Form apps with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

On both projects I have this App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="CameraSim.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <userSettings>
    <CameraSim.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="TRZICConn" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Data Source=UIC181;Initial Catalog=TRZIC-L;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxx;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False</value>
      </setting>
    </CameraSim.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

In one of them the project compiles without any problem, but in the other one don't.

The error is:

> You can not find schema information for the 'usersettings' element.

I have the same error with supportedRuntime, version, sku, setting, etc.

What have I forgotten?

I have also test this [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms229207%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but I'm having the same problems. And on that page doesn't say anything about doing something else like adding a dll.

Comment: how can u have two different projects with one config file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute-element

did you had a look at this queston?

Comment: I'm trying to use the same <CameraSim.Properties.Settings> section with another name, but it doesn't compile. So I have decided to use the same App.config on both to check if I have missed something when I have changed <CameraSim.Properties.Settings> section's name. But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Alex I think this is not the problem because the same App.config works fine on one project.