# visual studio - app.config issues after upgrading from dotnet 2.0 to 4.5

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xsd

I've just upgraded my multi project winforms C# solution from dotnet 2.0 to 4.5. In the process, I also upgraded from visual studio 2010 to 2015.

I'm having some troubles with my app.config. After upgrading, I got a whole bunch of messages, along the lines of

> "Could not find schema information for the element
>   'loggingConfiguration'"

.

Some searching found the solution to be to generate a new schema ([How to fix Error: "Could not find schema information for the attribute/element" by creating schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute-element)).

This did clear up that issue, but now I'm getting warnings when I open the app.config when I mouse over blue lines, like

> "Imported schema for namespace 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' was
>   not resolved"

and

> "The global element 'configuration' has already been declared"

The schemas for my app.config are:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 14.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig45.xsd" "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\xml\Schemas\EntityFrameworkConfig_6_1_0.xsd" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\xml\Schemas\RazorCustomSchema.xsd"
>   "C:\xml\App.xsd"

I'll include a few images in the hope it makes my ramblings clearer:

[Could not find schema message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SQww.png)

[Mouse over message once "could not find schema" message went away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeKej.png)

Any assistance would be appreciated. Been working on this for hours now.

Comment: I get the 'could not find' stuff all the time - these are (i) messages only. Normally if you declared the config section correctly it is resolved at runtime just fine.

Comment: Oh - so these dont effect it reading the rest of the app.config file? Because I'm having trouble configuring it to allow me use dotnet v2.0 code with v4.5 (as per here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode), and I was thinking maybe these messages may have had something to do with it.
So I guess I had better make another posting for the mixed-mode issue.
Thanks.