# Could not find schema information for the attribute 'xxx'

Tags: c#, .net, settings, config

I'm trying to save some settings (such as my connection) string in a .config file. Most of the tutorials I see online on how to create a .config file state that I should manually add an existing one, but my program has already created one automatically and I have the following code inside it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup><system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc812dsac44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data></configuration>
```

Now when I click the properties of my app.config file I get no error messages. But when I just click inside the text area I get the following 3 messages:

```
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'version'.
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'supportedRuntime'.
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku'.
```

So I created another app.config file and named it 'app2.config'. But when I copy the following code

```
      <appSettings>
    <add key="path226" value="Application.StartupPath" />
  </appSettings>
```

and try to retrieve the value by this code

```
MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path226"]);
```

I get a blank message box. If I try the same code within 'app.config' it works but I get the 3 error messages. I'm not sure whether I have to create my own app.config file or use the existing one. And If I have to use the existing one how can I solve my error ? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have your app.config open, go to the Properties window and click the `...` on the Schemas property. In the window that opens, look for "DotNetConfig.xsd" in the 'File Name' column. Is it there? If so, make sure there is a check mark under the "Use" column. (You can right-click and 'Use selected schemas' if it's not)

---

Or try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965640/1202807

> 1. Right-click on the project icon in Solution Explorer and choose "Properties".
> 2. Go to the "Application" tab and choose an earlier .NET target framework.
> 3. Save changes.
> 4. Go to the "Application" tab and choose the initial .NET target framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luci, but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Did any of the other answers from that question work? There are several there.

Comment: Yeah I tried all the answers posted on there. I actually checked around 3 - 4 different threads before I posted my question.