# Could not find schema information for the element/attribute xxx XAML

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I have like 180 Messages like :

`Could not find schema information for the element'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation:VisualStateGroup`'

All of those messages are in the xaml files of my uwp UI's. Should i ignore them or how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are existing `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation` that you cant add the `VisualStateGroup`

If you write the `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"`
 in the xmlns ,it will say the error.

But if some time the vs have not clean the Bin folder and Obj folder,there may be strange problems.

I think you can be fisrt check the nuget to found the merge and the second way is to clean the bin folder and obj folder.

Try update the vs may be solve it.

And you should right the file to view its property that the Compile options is right.

See:[How to fix Error: "Could not find schema information for the attribute/element" by creating schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute-element)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965640/6116637