# Could not find schema information for the attribute - Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, umbraco

I've discovered wierd messages in my Error list.

I got 28 messages for different attributes in my Web.config file saying:

```
Could not find schema information for the attribute '___'
```

With elements like

- configSource
- BaseRestExtensions
- log4net
- security
- settings
- umbracoConfiguration

and more!

I had a problem logging in with Umbraco and my guess is that this could be occouring the problem. What is this? Why is this happening? And how do i solve this?

THANKS

Comment: Seems like your web.config is corrupt somehow. Download Umbraco files and compare with your current web.config. Something must be missing... either files OR invalid config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute-element. This most likely isn't an Umbraco issue.