# XML verification using XSD is failing

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an issue with a simple **XSD** loaded via a XmlSchemaSet object and **XML** paresed using a XmlReaderSettings

Here is my XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Properties" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Item" minOccurs="0">                            
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This following XML will generate an error on line 5 ("Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Name'.at line 5:11  :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <Properties>
                <Item Name="OBJECT">
                    <Item Name="CONTENT"/>
                </Item>
            </Properties>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

What is wrong in my XSD?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute-element

Comment: @obi, there is nothing in that Q/A that will be useful for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the schema for the `Item` element.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an definition for the second level Item and it's attributes.

The following should be under your top level item

```
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Item">
                              <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                              </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                          </xs:sequence>
                          <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        </xs:complexType>
```

So it looks like this

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Properties" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Item" minOccurs="0">                            
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Item">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                              <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Either that, or your first Item should be self terminating if you only want one level of item.  But even so you then have to define the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that nothing is wrong with your XSD, and something is wrong with your schema processor. Here is what Saxon reports:

```
Saxon-EE 9.8.0.3J from Saxonica
Java version 1.8.0_121
Using license serial number V005192
Loading schema document file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xsd
Finished loading schema document file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xsd
Schema checking successful. Time: 738ms. Memory: 37Mb.
Using parser org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Processing file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml
Validation time: 244ms. Memory: 40Mb.
Validation successful
```

Your element declaration for `Item` has neither a `simpleType` or `complexType` child, nor a `type` attribute. The relevant rule in XSD part 1 is in §3.3.2, where it says that the effective {type definition} is:

> The type definition corresponding to the `<simpleType>` or `<complexType>`
>   element information item in the [children], if either is present,
>   otherwise the type definition ·resolved· to by the ·actual value· of
>   the type [attribute], otherwise the {type definition} of the element
>   declaration ·resolved· to by the ·actual value· of the
>   substitutionGroup [attribute], if present, otherwise the ·ur-type
>   definition·.

So in this case it is "the ·ur-type definition·", which is just a fancy name for `xs:anyType` (see §3.4.7) which allows any content.

Sadly Microsoft haven't updated their schema processor for about 15 years and bugs like this are not unknown.

This suggests you have 3 ways forward:

- Submit a bug to Microsoft and wait 15 years for a resolution
- Switch to a different schema processor (e.g. Saxon)
- Work around the bug by declaring the required type for element `Item`.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your thorough explanation. I'll skip option #1 :)