# C# Visual Studio 2012 Express configuration element is not declared

Tags: configuration, initialization, element

I have the following issue and I was not able to find anything sufficient in order to resolve it.

Before debugging my application I get a warning that says configuration element is not declared. The app compiles and works fine though. I recently tried to add a connection string in the configuration section and pull it back in the app. Then I get a proper error when it tries to access it saying "Configuration system failed to initialize"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections />
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
   </startup>
   <system.net>
      <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
   </system.net>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>two basichttpbindings here</bindings>
      <client>two endpoints here that bind with the basic httpbindings above. This is irrelevant as it was added even after the problem appeared</client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Nobody has provided a sufficient answer in the fora so far. Has something changed or does anybody know anything related to that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you post the config file **remember to take out any sensitive info**

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      two basichttpbindings here
    </bindings>
    <client>
      two endpoints here that bind with the basic httpbindings above. This is irrelevant as it was added even after the problem appeared
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: This is without the connection string at the moment

Comment: No I didnt. if you are talking about this:
<configuration xmlns="schema URL">
I tried it as well:

Message 1 Could not find schema information for the element 'schema URL:configuration'. C:\Users\jtournas\Desktop\Footprint 1.2.2\Footprint\App.config 2 2 Footprint

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816916/fix-the-global-element-configuration-has-already-been-declared

Comment: Thanks Christian. It says
"Make sure the EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.xsd is in %Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio [version] \Xml\Schemas\"

I don't have it there.. I installed Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 and it's still not there. What should I do? I am using VS Studio 2012 Express.