# Unable to remove DotNetConfig.xsd schema reference when targeting 4.5.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I have a configuration file that has element errors throughout and intellisense does not work. The main problem is a **"The global element 'configuration' has already been declared." warning**. I discovered that the culprit is because both the DotNetConfig45.xsd and DotNetConfig.xsd and schemas are being referenced under the "XML\Schemas..." option. The problem is that nothing I do will remove the DotNetConfig.xsd from being reference; Visual Studio just ignores my attempts to say not to use it or remove it. A reboot does **not** work either.

If I change my target framework to 4.5.0, then everything is fine with my config file except I can't compile the project because the dependent projects are in 4.5.1.

I've tried searching the web for any answers and no luck. The StackOverflow topic of [Fix: The Global element 'configuration' has already been declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816916/fix-the-global-element-configuration-has-already-been-declared) is referring to a different situation and it seems other users had issues when going the other way (4.5 to 4.0). I'm trying to use 4.5 and I do notice if I switch to 4.0, I do not have the problem.