# The Global element 'configuration' has already been declared when adding .net 2.0 web service reference to MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am getting build failure due to warning in my web.config. Everything was fine before I added .net 2.0 Web service reference to the MVC project. I got warnings of Global element '{element name}' has already been declared for all the elements in my web.config.  Searching has only turned up different issues than the one I am having.

Is there any way to fix this issue, perhaps by telling the configuration manager to ignore the config file in the referenced WS assembly?

I can not use the regular service reference as I am not able to call it via https. Or is there a way to reference the 2.0 web service as the regular service reference that can be invoked via https/ssl connection?

Edit: I also have a WCF service reference declared in the project, will that complicate the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. I don't have to add .net 2.0 WS reference to the project. I can use  in web.config to specify the transport protocol to be https.

However, it is wired that adding a web reference would invalidate the web.config elements. I would like to learn the cause of that and would appreciate your input.